# How to update a window in Tkinter after closing other window: Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create an inventory system for a school project.  It is supposed to allow people to enter food items into categories that they create.

I am having difficulty trying to refresh the window that lists the categories that 1 food item can be added to.

```
class AddTab:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.minsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.geometry('800x480+0+0')

        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'ADD TO CATEGORY')
        self.label.pack(anchor = 'n')

        self.frame.pack()

        catnames = open('categorynames.txt','r').read().splitlines()

        for name in catnames:
            addbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = '+1 '+name, width = 20, command = lambda name = name: self.addtocategory(name))
            addbutton.pack()

        addnewcat = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'ADD NEW CATEGORY', width = 100, command = self.addnewcategory)
        addnewcat.pack(anchor = 's')
```

This code does the mainloop switchy switchy thing.

```
def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainMenu(root)
    root.geometry('800x480+0+0')
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the code for the window that adds a new category to appear on the AddTab window.

```
class NewCategory:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.minsize(width = 400, height = 240)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 400, height = 240)
        self.master.geometry('400x240+0+0')

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'ADD NEW CATEGORY')
        self.label.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.newcatentry = tk.Entry(self.frame, width = 50)
        self.newcatentry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        quitbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'QUIT', width = 25, command = self.closewindow)
        quitbutton.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        enterbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'ENTER', width = 25, command = self.entryget)
        enterbutton.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def entryget(self):
        entrydata = self.newcatentry.get()
        catnameopen = open('categorynames.txt','a')
        catnameopen.write(entrydata+'\n')
        catnameopen.close
        catnamefile = open(entrydata+'.txt','a')
        catnamefile.close

        if os.stat(entrydata+'.txt').st_size == 0:
            categoryedit = open(entrydata+'.txt', 'w')
            categoryedit.write('0')
            print('it worked')
            categoryedit.close
            print('derp')

        self.master.destroy()

    def closewindow(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

When I enter the new name, it does everything it's supposed to except for update the AddTab with the new category as a button.

A lot of what I've searched for on the internet says that the mainloop does the 'event handling' or updating.  I'm not too sure what this entails, especially if many programs I've seen have all their 'widgets' in the `__init__`.

I am trying to learn Python on my own and it going decently.  Much of this is probably bad (terrible) programming and whatnot but it is my first foray into programming and I am willing to learn.

If someone wants to look at the full code I can post it as well.

EDIT:

Here is the full code as requested:

```
    import tkinter as tk
import os

filetuple = ('categorynames', 'barcodes')
for filename in filetuple:
    fileopen = open(filename+'.txt','a')
    fileopen.close

catnameopen = open('categorynames.txt','r').read().splitlines()
print(catnameopen)
for categoryname in catnameopen:
    print(categoryname)
    categoryamt = open(categoryname+'.txt','a')
    categoryamt.close

    if os.stat(categoryname+'.txt').st_size == 0:
        categoryedit = open(categoryname+'.txt', 'w')
        categoryedit.write('0')
        print('it worked')
        categoryedit.close
        print('derp')
    else:
        print("not needed")

class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.minsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.geometry('800x480+0+0')
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.addtabbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'ADD FOOD', width = 100, command = self.addtabwindow)
        self.addtabbutton.pack()

        self.subtabbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'SUBTRACT FOOD', width = 100, command = self.subtabwindow)
        self.subtabbutton.pack()

        self.quitbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'QUIT', width = 100, command = self.closewindow)
        self.quitbutton.pack()

        self.frame.pack()

    def closewindow(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def addtabwindow(self):
        self.addtabwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = AddTab(self.addtabwindow)

    def subtabwindow(self):
        self.subtabwindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = SubTab(self.subtabwindow)

class NewCategory:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.minsize(width = 400, height = 240)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 400, height = 240)
        self.master.geometry('400x240+0+0')

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'ADD NEW CATEGORY')
        self.label.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.newcatentry = tk.Entry(self.frame, width = 50)
        self.newcatentry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

        quitbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'QUIT', width = 25, command = self.closewindow)
        quitbutton.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        enterbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'ENTER', width = 25, command = self.entryget)
        enterbutton.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def entryget(self):
        entrydata = self.newcatentry.get()
        catnameopen = open('categorynames.txt','a')
        catnameopen.write(entrydata+'\n')
        catnameopen.close
        catnamefile = open(entrydata+'.txt','a')
        catnamefile.close

        if os.stat(entrydata+'.txt').st_size == 0:
            categoryedit = open(entrydata+'.txt', 'w')
            categoryedit.write('0')
            print('it worked')
            categoryedit.close
            print('derp')

        self.master.destroy()

    def closewindow(self):
        self.master.destroy()

class AddTab:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.minsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.geometry('800x480+0+0')

        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'ADD TO CATEGORY')
        self.label.pack(anchor = 'n')

        self.frame.pack()

    def loopstuff(self):

        catnames = open('categorynames.txt','r').read().splitlines()

        for name in catnames:
            addbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = '+1 '+name, width = 20, command = lambda name = name: self.addtocategory(name))
            addbutton.pack()

        addnewcat = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'ADD NEW CATEGORY', width = 100, command = self.addnewcategory)
        addnewcat.pack(anchor = 's')


    def addnewcategory(self):
        self.addnewcategory = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = NewCategory(self.addnewcategory)

    def addtocategory(self, name):
        print(name)
        nameamt = open(name+'.txt','r').read()
        nameamt = int(nameamt) + 1
        newamt = open(name+'.txt','w')
        newamt.write(str(nameamt))
        newamt.close

class SubTab:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.minsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.geometry('800x480+0+0')

        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'SUBTRACT FROM CATEGORY')
        self.label.pack()

        catnames = open('categorynames.txt','r').read().splitlines()

        #for name in catnames:
            #self.catnamebutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = name, width = 30)
            #self.catnamebutton.pack()

        self.frame.pack()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainMenu(root)
    root.geometry('800x480+0+0')
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The SubTab can basically be ignored as it will basically be a copy of AddTab.

Comment: I suspect the issue you're having isn't in any of the code you've posted.  Both `NewCategory` and `AddTab` are `Frames` (also, you should be using inheritance... Python 3 C'mon).  The issue your question title describes (about "windows"), would be from having multiple Tk `Application`'s.  Where is the code of yours that calls/constructs `NewCategory`?  It will probably do something like a `show()` somewhere?

Comment: @Tersosauros I updated the post to include the full code.  I have been using PythonProgramming as my main resource for this project as well as various Stackoverflow posts.  The problem I think I'm having is that I basically need to repeat the 'for loop' that creates the buttons corresponding to each category without creating a whole new set of buttons along with the old buttons.  The code works fine if I close the window and reopen it.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code that creates an AddTab instance. How is it called?  You also have to have an addnewcategory() function in AddTab for the command in the button press.  This code adds one button from outside the class to show how that is done, and will add a new button every time you click the ADDNEWCATEGORY button.  Obviously this is not complete as it does not include any of your other code, but shows how the button press works.

```
class AddTab:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.minsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.maxsize(width = 800, height = 480)
        self.master.geometry('800x480+0+0')

        ## separate frame for Add To Category button so 
        ## new buttons can be added to self.frame in order
        self.cat_button_frame=tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'ADD TO CATEGORY')
        self.label.pack(anchor = 'n')

        self.frame.pack()
        self.cat_button_frame.pack()
        self.but_num=1
##        catnames = open('categorynames.txt','r').read().splitlines()

        for name in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            addbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = '%s-%s ' %(self.but_num, name),
                                  width = 20)
            addbutton.pack()
            self.but_num += 1

        addnewcat = tk.Button(self.cat_button_frame, text = 'ADD NEW CATEGORY',
                    width = 100, command = self.addnewcategory)
        addnewcat.pack(anchor = 's')

    def addnewcategory(self):
        """ for simplicity, new category is named "new cat" 
            and the button is not connected to any function
        """
        tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'new cat-%d' %(self.but_num), width = 20).pack()
        self.but_num += 1

master=tk.Tk()
AT=AddTab(master)
## add new category from outside the class
AT.addnewcategory()
master.mainloop()
```